# why test SynonymGraphFilter Lucene doesn't work?

Tags: lucene, synonym

I trying to test synonym Graph but doesn't work how as i expected and don't return the correct answer.

This is the createComponents custom method in my custom analyzer

```
    public SuggestAnalizer(SynonymMap synonymMap) {
       this.synonymMap = synonymMap;
       this.stopList = Collections.emptyList();
    }


    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s) {

        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer();
        TokenStream tokenStream = new SynonymGraphFilter(tokenizer,    synonymMap, true);

        tokenStream = new FlattenGraphFilter(tokenStream);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, tokenStream);
    }
```

This is the Test code

```
    String entrada = "ALCALDE KOOPER";
    String salida = "FEDERICO COOPER";

    SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);

    CharsRef input = SynonymMap.Builder.join(entrada.split(" "), new CharsRefBuilder());
    CharsRef output = SynonymMap.Builder.join(salida.split(" "), new CharsRefBuilder());


    builder.add(output, input, true);

    suggestAnalizer = new SuggestAnalizer(builder.build());

    TokenStream tokenStream = suggestAnalizer.tokenStream("field", entrada2);

    assertTokenStreamContents(tokenStream, new String[]{
            "FEDERICO"
    });

    assertAnalyzesTo(suggestAnalizer, entrada, new String[]{
            "FEDERICO"
    });
```

I expected the assertion work changing the "ALCALDE KOOPER" string for her synonym "FEDERICO COOPER", but this doesn't happen.

Someone know where is my error or why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Please tell us what the error you're seeing is.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I expected the assertion work changing the "ALCALDE KOOPER" string for her synonym "FEDERICO COOPER", but this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for these behaviour, is that you add multiword synonym from
`FEDERICO COOPER` to `ALCALDE KOOPER` (in the code, I saw adding link from output (which is `FEDERICO COOPER`) to input, which is `ALCALDE KOOPER`)

Later you're testing synonyms for a token `FEDERICO`, but there is no connection from it, that's why you get empty response and an assertion error. So, if you will add synonyms from `FEDERICO` to `ALCALDE`.

But, even if you will do that, there is a mistake with building `SynonymMap`, you used `ignoreCase` param with `true` value, which means:

> case-folds input for matching with Character#toLowerCase(int).
>   Note, if you set this to true, it's your responsibility to lowercase the input entries when you create the SynonymMap

So, rather you need to use lowercased version in testing or set `ignoreCase` to `false`

You could check a reference code [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene6/src/main/java/EntradaSalida.java)